# GROUP BY and division

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot

In GBQ table i have structure(page_location, event_name, count) event_name can have value 'view', 'add_basket'. I want receive structure - GROUP BY(page_location), (value count from event_name = 'add_basket' / value count from event_name = 'view'). I tried PIVOT and OVER am already confused how to do it.

There is

```
page_location, event_name, count
A, view, 100
A, add_basket, 10
A, view, 200
A, add_basket, 20`
```

Necessary

```
page_location, count
A, 0.1
B, 0.1
```

[My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JFB6.png)

Comment: Did you try countif? (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#countif)   With this function you can compute the both counts and thus take the ratio of them.

Comment: It will be much easier with a test data and a desired output. Can you provide that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select page_location, add_basket/view as count
from your_table
pivot (sum(count) for event_name in ('view','add_basket'))
```

Comment: Won't page location repeat?

Comment: just try and see :o) - but, no - they will not!

Comment: btw, you can use your cte and test it :o)

Comment: Just tested. My bad. It won't repeat. Will delete my answer. 

Comment: sure. no problem. consider voting up if it helped you to learn something new! i hope it is a case  :o)

Comment: Yes, thanks, it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine function `sum` and `case when` to solve your problem. My solution is following:

```
select page_location
,sum(case when event_name = 'add_basket' then count else 0 end) 
/ sum(case when event_name = 'view' then count else 0 end) end as ratio

from gbq

group by page_location
```

Comment: This sol wont give the expected output. The o/p should be (10+20)/(100+200) = 0.1. But in your case you are just summing up 1s.

Comment: You are right! I misunderstood the problem.